# How to install SQL Server Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server, sql-server-express

While installing Visual Studio 2010, I saw an option to install SQL Express. I checked that option assuming it would install SQL Server Express as well, but apparently it didn't. When I type ssms.exe in Run, it says it cannot find it. Also, I do not see SQL Server Management Studio under Programs--> Microsoft SQL Server 2008. All I see is:

```
Import and Export Data (64 bit)
SQL Server Configuration Manager
SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting
SQL Server Installation Center (64 bit)
```

When I click on `SQL Server Installation Center (64 bit)`, it asks me to **Browse for SQL Server 2008 Installation Media**, but I am not sure where it is located at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure SQL Express doesn't include SSMS out of the box.

You can [download Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) from Microsoft.

The error you're reporting does make it seem like it's not fully installed.  You can get an [installable stand-alone copy of MSSQL Express 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXP08V2/enus/) from MS as well, which you could possibly use to repair or reinstall it.

Comment: This is it.  When you download MSSQL, you need to select the options (w/Tools).